# How can I show multiple repeating custom field values in a single cell on a report?

Tags: civireport

We woud like a simple contact report which, rather than showing a single row for each custom field (with repeating contact name on each row), shows a single row for the contact and shows all the repeating custom data in a single cell.

Could anyone share a simple reporting template example that does this?

Answer (score 1):

I've investigated this myself, but haven't had to do it yet.  Broadly, you would use the `GROUP_CONCAT` MySQL function.  You can see examples of this being used on [core contribution reports](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/OrganizationSummary.php#L178) for displaying multiple credit card types for contributions paid in multiple installments with different cards.

I also have a fork of the [salutations](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.jlacey.salutations/blob/no-addressee/salutations.php#L429) extension that provides a UI for exporting multiple-record custom groups as part of an export.  Instead of putting all the data in a single cell, I break the data out into multiple columns, but all on the same row.

You could also use the [SQL Tasks extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sql-tasks-extension-configurable-recurring-tasks) to generate the report using pure SQL, if you need a quicker solution and can trade off some configurability.